# Excel : Faster Vlookup using 2 vlookups

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 workbooks. 1 workbook has 780k rows and the 2nd has 290k rows. Using just one vlookup took hours to process. I found out about using 2 vlookups for faster calculations for large data sets but there were no results. I'm using 2 columns for the vlookup and both columns are alphanumeric.

This was my formula

```
=IF(A1=VLOOKUP(A1,LargeDataset,1,TRUE),VLOOKUP(A1,LargeDataSet,1,TRUE),NA())
```

I sorted tried sorting A to Z and not sorted.

Comment: Show a minimal sample data set that exhibits the problem of showing no results.

Comment: Why not use a database? They are optimized for lookup. Excel, for all of its strengths, is [not a database](https://seesharpdotnet.wordpress.com/2017/08/05/excel-is-not-a-database/).

Comment: I can't disclose the data because it's confidential sorry.